# Why are these images not cycling through while using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to cycle through 3 images, stacked on top of one another. The jQuery I am using does not have any effect on the images and I cannot see what the problem is. I'd really love some help! Cheers!!

HTML:

```
        <div id="cycler">
        <img class="active" src="images/dubcity4.jpg" alt="my image"/>
        <img src="images/dubcity2.jpg" alt="my image"/>
        <img src="images/dubcity3.jpg" alt="my image"/>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
      #cycler{position:relative;}
      #cycler img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
      #cycler img.active{z-index:3}
```

JavaScript:

```
function cycleImages(){
    var $active = $('#cycler.active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
    $next.css('z-index', 2);
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval('cycleImages()',2000);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var $active = $('#cycler.active');
```

to that:

```
var $active = $('#cycler .active');
```

in your code you are trying to find element with id="cycler" AND class="active" which is wrong

Also try to pass function to a setInterval instead of a string

```
setInterval(cycleImages,2000);
```

See jSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ygV3z/

Comment: tried that there, it is still not doing anything. Is there other typo's I wonder?

Comment: using setInterval(cycleImages,2000); it is now working! Thanks for your help! appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For sure this is wrong: `$('#cycler.active');`

You should have `$('#cycler .active');` since `.active` is descendant of `#cycler`. Your selector is looking for a element with id = `cycler` that also have `active` class assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo in your CSS selector.
Just fix it by changing this:

```
var $active = $('#cycler.active');
```

into the following:

```
var $active = $('#cycler .active');
```

Comment: tried that there, it is still not doing anything. Is there other typo's I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has an `each` method that could help you cycle through DOM elements:

```
$("#cycler img").each(function(key, obj) {
   // fetch the arguments passed
   var args = arguments;
   // get a jquery accessible form of each object
   var obj = $(obj);
   // do stuff
});
```

You can match on names or classes, or even the attributes if they are the same. I'm sure better skilled folks could tell you if 1 is faster than the other, but the notation for attributes would be `$("#cycler [data-pick='true']")` to match each image within `#cycler` that is defined as follows: `<img src="..." data-pick="true" />`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: changing to #cycler .active has not fixed the issue? it is still the exact same.

Comment: That's not quite what he wanted. His looping method is good for what he's doing.

Comment: Perhaps try the `each` JQuery method - it might be less confusing and work - I find that it is clearer for me to understand with the nested function callback. Everyone else - I'm laying no claim to being a guru, just trying to help.

Comment: Submitted a correction - the last post's syntax was super confusing (sorry!) - To Claudio's point, what "fixes" the issue with your reference would be `#cycler .active` instead of `#cycler.active`: The 1st will match elements of class `active` within a parent of id `cycler`, whereas the second will match an element of id `cycler` AND of class `active` - hence none of the images in your sample code

Answer (score 0):

As everyone here has said, you need a space between your CSS selectors to denote that you want descendants. Also, you need to use `:first-child`, not `:first`.

Also, you can not pass a string into `setTimeout()`. Furthermore, `setTimeout()` expects *an actual callback function* in its first argument, *not what that function returns*. What you're doing is very similar to this:

```
function looper() {
    $(this).hide();
}
$("img").each("looper()");
```

That doesn't make any sense, does it?

Now, the fixed code:

```
function cycleImages(){
    var $active = $('#cycler .active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first-child');
    $next.css('z-index', 2);
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(cycleImages,2000);
})
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/L4D7r/